# Is GPS gives its location in airplane mode?

Tags: android

I am developing location tracking android app using Location Manager  in that i am trying to get location  in airplane mode via GPS but GPS provider  will not call its callback method to  get location. I want to know that, is GPS gives its location in airplane mode?  Please help.  Thanks .

Comment: http://backcountrynavigator.com/using-android-gps-airplane-mode/

Comment: GPS works just fine in flight mode but the time to first fix is longer since there's no network connectivity to help download the satellite almanac data.